How to use this crystal oscillator?
I recently bought a 315Mhz crystal oscillator off of Amazon but I can’t figure out how to use it nor can I find any information online about it.

The only thing I can find on them is that picture.
I would like to know what the pin out is and the type of circuit needed to make it run. If anyone has used these before I would really appreciate help.

In what do you want to make it run, output a 315 MHz square wave for something, or make a RF transceiver with it, or something else? Please note that if you bought something from Amazon and you have no data sheet to tell the parameters of what you bought, we can't tell in what kind of circuit your unknown component will run. And that is not a crystal oscillator, it is not an oscillator at all, and likely a SAW resonator instead of a crystal.

You can purchase 315/433MHz remote control transmitter boards that incorporate these SAW resonators for a couple of dollars. This eliminates any question of circuitry.

@Justme the goal, which I should have specified, is just to creat a 315Mhz sine wave as the output

This is not a crystal oscillator; it's just a bare crystal. The simplest way to use it is to connect it to a 74LVC1GX04 crystal driver IC as a Pierce oscillator, but you can also make other types of crystal-stabilized oscillator with bare transistors and reactive components.
The pin that is visibly attached to the outer shell is just a shield pin, and should be connected to ground. The other two pins are the two terminals of the crystal, and are interchangeable.

More specifically, a surface acoustic wave (SAW) resonator.

It's only a resonator not an oscillator.
Here are two application circuits courtesy SHENZHEN YANGXING TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD.


Specs for OP's 315MHz version R315 here

Do you know how I would choose the capacitor and resistor values?

Hi Marcus Marchese , Do hope you find this link helpful. https://jap.hu/electronic/rf/434MHz_SAW-based_oscillators_and_transmitters.pdf
